# Always resolve conflicts in Git with ours or theirs

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github-desktop

I'm trying to setup Git and GitHub Desktop in an "artist-friendly" way for Unity.

I've seen different suggestions and various `.gitattributes` files, but none of them have been satisfactory. One of the reasons why is that most require setting up a custom merge driver and use Unity's YAML merge tool. However, this is both not ideal in our environment and I'm not always happy about the results I get from Unity's merge tool.

Unity's asset serializtion is set to **Force Text** and we have **visible meta files**.

Ideally, I would like all merge conflicts to be resolved by either choosing *ours* or *theirs*. The exception could be around source code where merging is meaningful and easily readable.

### First attempt

One of my attempts included setting up the `.gitattributes` to handle Unity scene files like so:

`*.unity merge=binary -diff -text`

This gives the desired behaviour in GitHub Desktop, but unfortunately also makes the Git history grow rapidly because all changes are treated as binary.

[image: GitHub Desktop resolve]

### Second attempt

Another attempt was to do:

`*.unity merge=binary diff -text`

This made delta changes work nicely and prevents the Git history from growing rapidly, but now every merge conflict is auto resolved with the changes from the user doing the merge. Also not ideal.

[image: GitHub Desktop resolve]

### Git LFS

We are also using Git LFS for other binary files, so a solution could also just be to store all Unity asset files in LFS as well. But that too creates problems with conflicts.

In my `.gitattributes` I have

`*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text`

When a conflict happens, GitHub Desktop tries to merge the binary files, resulting in a broken file (this behaviour goes beyond me). What would be the resolution here?

#### Note 1

I am still learning more about Git and still feel new to it, but the amount of "good advice" on the web does make things more confusing. I have of course also looked for an answer in the Git documentation, but couldn't find an answer to this particular question. I am really just trying to understand how the `.gitattributes` works and what is possible with it.

Suggestions for other clients are also welcome, but being *artist friendly* is key.

#### Note 2

I am aware that I could use `git checkout --theirs -- path/to/file` but this isn't exactly what I would call *artist friendly*.

#### Note 3

Maybe this is more a feedback request for GitHub Desktop, but I thought maybe there would be a way to configure Git to use the desired behaviour. Preferably using `.gitattributes` only.

#### Edit

Upon investigation, the Git LFS merge appears to just replace the contents of `image.png` with a pointer. Is that right?

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
<<<<<<< HEAD
oid sha256:eebb5d4ccca98dec56306a22cfd518de0d066674f5c4a4859daef7fe0dc54d4d
size 12748
=======
oid sha256:13c917ff0743750c72d0229f6311db52b2663790a2ef3774d1b661e516bf6852
size 15275
>>>>>>> 669836a1b32690baf4ef84dac711c44d274966c4
```

That issue seems to be related to GitHub Desktop: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/7166

A suggested solution is to add `binary` like this:

`*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text binary`

Comment: The directives in `.gitattributes` (such as a `merge` driver or a label `binary`) have no real effect on the *stored size* of a Git repository, which is determined instead by the contents of each file. Commits aren't deltas: they are snapshots. Packfiles do use deltas, but they are created long after any merging has occurred. (None of this is really relevant to your issue, which is UI / UX.) Re the edit: yes, that is exactly how Git-LFS works: you tell LFS *don't store this file in Git, store it elsewhere and have Git keep a file-locator (sort of a URL) instead.*

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however I did a test where I noted the size difference after each commit. The first test used `*.unity merge=binary -diff -text` and resulted in the local `.git` folder growing by about 1.6 MB for each commit. After setting `*.unity merge=binary diff -text` the `.git` folder almost didn't increase in size. GitHub desktop also showed the text deltas and my guess would be that only the difference was saved and not the entire "binary" file (not really binary). Whereas when I initially comitted the scene file, the `.git` folder grew by about 1.6 MB

Comment: It's possible that GitHub Desktop is doing its own thing, bypassing Git entirely. That seems a bit unlikely. The `diff` attribute in Git merely controls how *displayed* diffs are handled; see [the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), particularly the section titled "Generating diff text".

Comment: It seems more likely that you crossed the threshold for generating a pack file. Git will take "loose" objects (which really are snapshots, just zlib-compressed) and turn them into "packs" in which multiple objects are stored into a single file and are delta-compressed against other objects in the same file. This can shrink the repository quite a bit *if* the delta-compression goes well. Binary files can be delta-compressed as this does not use diff at all.